# Primality test based on the properties of Pascal Triangle partial sum of a given diagonal

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, primality-test

The test involves a partial sum of a diagonal whose second element is a prime. Because of the symmetry of Pascal Triangle each prime has two diagonals parallel to the sides of the triangle. These two diagonals meet at the central binomial coefficient (cbc). The number of elements of each diagonal up to the cbc is always $(p-1)$ (with of course the cbc element included).

**Observation 1**: every element (except the first one equal to $1$) of such a diagonal is divisible by the prime $p$. This property is not shared by composites which have only some elements divisible by the composite.

Because of such divisibility property, it makes more sense to add all the elements up to and including the cbc before testing if the sum is divisible by the given prime. Therefore the sum must be calculated. It turned out that the next element after the cbc, the $p-th$ element, provides that sum after subtracting $1$ (the first element of a diagonal). This comes from the fact that the $p-th$ element and the elements not aligned with it form a hockey stick. So the sum of $(p-1)$ elements is given by the $((p-th) -1)$.

**Observation 2**: For a prime, the sum of $(p-1)$ elements is always divisible by $p^3$. No proof is avalaible at this time.

So there is a need to calculate the sum using the hockey stick value which itself needs to be calculated. It turns out that the hockey stick value is half of the $p-th$ cbc. The cbc value is given by $v=(2n)!/(n!)^2$.

Here's a numerical example to illustrate the method.

We consider $p=5$. The $(5-1)=4$ elements are $5,15,35,70$. The value of $n$ is always given by the value of $p$ so $n=5$ and $v=10!/(5!)^2=252$. The value of the sum is simply $s=(252/2 - 1)=125=5^3$. $5$ is the only prime for which the sum is $p=5^3$.

Other sums involving larger primes than $5$ will have other factors beside $p^3$.

For $p=7$, we have $s=(3432/2 -1)=1715=5*7^3$
For $p=11$, we have $s=(705432/2-1)=352715=5*53*11^3$

There is a table of $500$ values of central binomial coefficients here:

https://oeis.org/A000984/b000984.txt

**Question:** How does this primality test compare to other well-known methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "Observation 2" is [Wolstenholme's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem). The converse is still an open problem, and regarded as quite hard.

On the time complexity of the algorithm, it's pretty bad. It requires calculating $\binom{2n-1}{n-1} \mod n^3$, which will take $\mathcal{\Omega}(n)$ time. It will probably be quite a bit worse, as the numbers you calculate will be massive, and it's not obvious how to avoid using big integers and keep computations modulo $n^3$. For comparison, the simple trial divison algorithm runs in $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: thanks for pointing out Wolstenholme's theorem. I am aware that the  the central  binomial coefficients (cbc) grow really fast so the time complexity is 'pretty bad" as you pointed out. However I am hoping that one day someone will come up with an efficient method of calculating the  cbc.

Comment: It would be interesting to test the method to see how it handles the pseudoprimes. I know $9$ (pseudoprime in base 10) doesn't pass the test since $24309/9^3=33.35$ so $9$ is definitely not a prime. (my calculator can't do large numbers).

Comment: @user25406 Calculating the central binomial coefficients quickly would be of no help to making the algorithm viable, as they have $\Theta(n)$ digits. One would have to find a way to calculate $\binom{2n-1}{n-1} \mod n^3$ quickly. Wolstenholme actually established that his theorem is equivalent to the pair of congruences $H_{p-1, 1} \equiv 0 \pmod{p^2}$ and $H_{p-1, 2} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, where $H_{n, m}$ is a generalized harmonic number. So this observation would allow one to implement this algorithm in $\mathcal{O}(n)$.

Comment: @user25406 Honestly, this algorithm just seems like an inferior version to a primality check via Wilson's theorem, which is also vastly inferior to all commonly used primality checks.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution and clarification of the issues involved.